# SyntaxError if executed with cron, OK if manually

Tags: django, cron, ubuntu

I'm trying to schedule a script with cron in kubuntu. If I execute the script manually line by line, it goes just fine, but scheduled with cron it raises the following SyntaxError:

```
  File "/opt/django/myproject/myapp/cron/test.sh", line 4
    python manage.py mycustomcommand
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The content of the script test.sh is as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/activate
cd /opt/django/myproject
python manage.py mycustomcommand
```

Basically the script activates a virtual enviroment where django is installed, then accesses to my project path, and then executes a custom django command. As said, this works fine if I do it manually.

I tried to schedule the script in cron with normal and root permissions also ("crontab -e" and "sudo crontab -e")

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests that you fire the command `python manage.py mycustomcommand` **from within the Python interpreter** (and not as a bash command).

You probably have something like

```
1 * * * * python /path/to/myscript/test.sh
```

in your crontab entry which is a mistake and it should be

```
1 * * * * /path/to/myscript/test.sh
```

instead.

Comment: You are right. My crontab entry was "* * * * * python /opt/django/myproject/myapp/cron/test.sh > /opt/django/myproject/log/test.log 2>&1". I removed "python". Now I have a permission problem: /bin/sh: 1: /opt/django/myproject/myapp/cron/test.sh: Permission denied

Comment: I gave permissions to the script (sudo chmod -x test.sh), but now aparently it doesn't find the script: /bin/sh: 1: /opt/django/.../test.sh: not found ¿?

Comment: @klautern Perhaps this is because you are running it via `sh`. Try adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the begining of the crontab file. Besides you want to do `chmod +x test.sh` not `-x` which removes permissions.

Comment: I've tried the SHELL change (also the +x) but: /bin/bash: /opt/django/myproject/myapp/cron/test2.sh: /bin/bash^M: intérprete erróneo: No existe el archivo o el directorio (**bad interpreter: No such file or directory**)

Comment: @klautern Change `/bin/bash` (in both files) to the result of calling `which bash` in shell on the server. If it gives you nothing then you don't have `bash` and you have to install it. If it gives you the same path `/bin/bash` then you have some serious configuration issue on the server. Anyway that becomes a different question.

Comment: Adding **bash** to the cron command worked. Thank you @freakish. * * * * * **bash** command